# Rust: BE to native in generic way

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a generic function that supposed to read various number primitive types (`u8`, `i16`, `u16`, `u32`, `f32` etc) from a byte slice:

```
fn read<T: bytemuck::Pod>(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
    if self.offset + size <= self.data.len() {
        let bytes: &[u8] = &self.data[self.offset..(self.offset + size)];
        self.offset += size;
        let value = *bytemuck::from_bytes(bytes);
        // TODO: Swap bytes from BE to native
        Some(value)
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Data is stored in the slice in Big Endian format, then I need to convert data to native byte order.

There are functions like `i32::from_be`, `f32::from_be_bytes`, but they are not part of any trait, so I cannot use them in generic way.

Also there is [a generic bswap intrinsic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.bswap.html), but I cannot use it with stable Rust compiler.

Comment: The [`num` crate](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/traits/trait.PrimInt.html#tymethod.from_be) seems to provide such traits.

Comment: It's nice library and solves almost all task, but what about floating point numbers?

Comment: yes, I can only think about something ugly... There exists the `Float` trait, with only two implementations: `f32` and `f64`. Maybe could you consider these two specific cases and transmute towards/from an integer of the same size?

Comment: @prog-fh You don't need to transmute, there exists `{f32, f64}::{to, from}_bits` to convert to/from `{u32, u64}`.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment, I thought that `PrimInt::from_be()` from the [`num` crate](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/traits/trait.PrimInt.html#tymethod.from_be) could help, but it was not so simple.
There is no `from_be_bytes()` in this trait; some unsafe operations are probably required to initialize these abstract integers from a sequence of bytes.
Moreover, if we implement our trait in a common way for any type considered as `PrimInt`, it is impossible to implement our trait differently when it comes to `f32` and `f64`: the compiler reports these implementations as conflicting with the one for `PrimInt` since in theory the `num` crate could decide in a future version to consider `f32` or `f64` as `PrimInt` (it won't happen, obviously, but the compiler is not aware of that).

As a second thought, it is probably better to rely on a macro in order to enumerate all the integer/real types which should implement our trait.
Sorry about my bad advice in the comments.

Please find below an example of what could be done.
Note that I decided to use a *sealed* trait in order to prevent from implementing such byte conversions for any other type outside the module.
You can always remove this limitation if you have good reasons.

```rust
mod pod_read_be_bytes {

    pub trait PodReadBeBytes: private::Sealed + Sized {
        fn read_be_bytes(
            bytes: &[u8],
            offset: &mut usize,
        ) -> Option<Self>;
    }

    fn read_bytes<const N: usize>(
        bytes: &[u8],
        offset: &mut usize,
    ) -> Option<[u8; N]> {
        let begin = *offset;
        let end = begin + N;
        if bytes.len() >= end {
            *offset = end;
            bytes[begin..end].try_into().ok()
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    mod private {
        pub trait Sealed {}
    }

    macro_rules! impl_pod_read_be_bytes {
        ($($t:ty),*) => {
            $(impl private::Sealed for $t {})*
            $(impl PodReadBeBytes for $t {
                fn read_be_bytes(
                    bytes: &[u8],
                    offset: &mut usize,
                ) -> Option<Self> {
                    const SZ: usize = std::mem::size_of::<$t>();
                    read_bytes::<SZ>(bytes, offset).map(
                        |a| Self::from_be_bytes(a)
                    )
                }
            })*
        }
    }

    impl_pod_read_be_bytes!(
        i8, u8, i16, u16, i32, u32, i64, u64, i128, u128, isize, usize, f32,
        f64
    );
}

fn main() {
    let bytes = &{
        const AMOUNT: usize = 2
            + std::mem::size_of::<i8>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<u8>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<i16>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<u16>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<i32>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<u32>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<i64>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<u64>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<i128>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<u128>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<isize>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<usize>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<f32>()
            + std::mem::size_of::<f64>();
        let mut data = Vec::with_capacity(AMOUNT);
        for i in 0..AMOUNT {
            data.push((1 + i % 255) as u8);
        }
        data
    };
    let mut offset = 0;
    use pod_read_be_bytes::PodReadBeBytes;
    println!("i8 ~~> {:?}", i8::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("u8 ~~> {:?}", u8::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("i16 ~~> {:?}", i16::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("u16 ~~> {:?}", u16::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("i32 ~~> {:?}", i32::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("u32 ~~> {:?}", u32::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("i64 ~~> {:?}", i64::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("u64 ~~> {:?}", u64::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("i128 ~~> {:?}", i128::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("u128 ~~> {:?}", u128::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("isize ~~> {:?}", isize::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("usize ~~> {:?}", usize::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("f32 ~~> {:?}", f32::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("f64 ~~> {:?}", f64::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
    println!("len: {}    offset: {}", bytes.len(), offset);
    println!("!!! i32 ~~> {:?}", i32::read_be_bytes(bytes, &mut offset));
}
/*
i8 ~~> Some(1)
u8 ~~> Some(2)
i16 ~~> Some(772)
u16 ~~> Some(1286)
i32 ~~> Some(117967114)
u32 ~~> Some(185339150)
i64 ~~> Some(1085386279523456278)
u64 ~~> Some(1664107662228069662)
i128 ~~> Some(41372893392955624638853358652142398766)
u128 ~~> Some(62723943866426273326751373236096482622)
isize ~~> Some(4557714575751136582)
usize ~~> Some(5136435958455749966)
f32 ~~> Some(3494990300.0)
f64 ~~> Some(2.6508648221291137e93)
len: 92    offset: 90
!!! i32 ~~> None
*/
```